# 27.5x.215 tubes in a 27.5x210 tire. How big of a problem

Tags: innertube

I wanted to install puncture resistant tubes on my mountain bike. Unfortunately the only size I could find were 27.5×.215 tunes and my tires are 27.5×.210. I got the tubes on, the beads seated and the tires inflated. I took it for a ride and intentionally hit some hard bumps, nothing happened. How big of a problem is the size difference? Should I expect these tubes to blow out or are they probably good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean a 27.5x2.15 tube in a 27.5x2.10 tire, that's a difference of 5 one-hundredths of an inch, or about 1 1/4 mm.

That's - not going to matter.

At all.

There'd be zero benefit in getting tubes that are labelled as exactly 27.5x2.10.  There's even a good chance those "smaller" tubes would actually be larger in reality - tube sizing isn't critical down to the mm.

Comment: That's what I was asking, thank you! I was worried because it was harder to get the beads seated than with the OEM tubes.

Comment: Agreed - you can generally go 10% over the nominal max size, and 20% under without significant issues.  This tube should be fine for 2.3" to 1.75", or 44-60 mm   Puncture resistant tubes are probably thicker butyl rubber and just a bit harder to manipulate, or perhaps there's sealant inside the tubes too.